# In ASP.NET Core, why are authorization handlers called even if authentication fails?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-authorization

There is a note in the docs for [Policy-based authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-6.0#what-should-a-handler-return) thay says:

> Authorization handlers are called even if authentication fails.

But there is no further explanation why.
What is the purpose of executing authorization handlers if user is not even authenticated?

Comment: From the same page: _"If a handler calls context.Succeed or context.Fail, all other handlers are still called. This allows requirements to produce side effects, such as logging, which takes place even if another handler has successfully validated or failed a requirement."_

Comment: Because [InvokeHandlersAfterFailure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizationoptions.invokehandlersafterfailure?view=aspnetcore-6.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authorization_AuthorizationOptions_InvokeHandlersAfterFailure) defaults to true, in which case all handlers are called.

Comment: Ok but what is the use-case scenario that we want to cover with that?